# Como excluir um conjunto de linhas específicas, listadas em um vetor, de um data frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Olá, possuo um data.frame com milhares de linhas e um vetor com as linhas que preciso deste data.frame, como faço para selecionar só as linhas da lista em um objeto separado?

Answer (score 2):

Suponha que vc tem um data.frame desta forma:

```
 df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
```

E que você queira selecionar apenas as linhas 1,5 e 8 que estão no vetor:

```
linhas <- c(1,5,8)
```

Então você pdoe selecioná-las e salvar em um novo objeto da seguinte forma:

```
df.novo <- df[linhas,]
df.novo
  a b
1 1 1
5 5 5
8 8 8
```

Se você quisesse excluir as linhas 1,5 e 8 você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
df.novo <- df[-linhas, ]
df.novo
    a  b
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
6   6  6
7   7  7
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa o dplyr():

Importar pacotes

```
library(dplyr)
```

Data Frame de exemplo

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
```

removendo linha 1 e 2, por exemplo:

```
df <- df %>% slice(3:n())
```

Answer (score 0):

Para uma situação onde é necessário maior mão-de-obra para manipulação de dados, e esperado bom rendimento, o uso do pacote `data.table` pode ser de grande ajuda.

Deixo aqui um breve exemplo utilizando o *toy data* de @Daniel Falbel.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
df <- data.table::data.table(df)

linhas <- c(1,5,8)

df <- df[,.SD[-linhas]]
df
```

```
> df
    a  b
1:  2  2
2:  3  3
3:  4  4
4:  6  6
5:  7  7
6:  9  9
7: 10 10
```